# ¿Cómo agregar clases de CSS para hacer animaciones?

Tags: javascript, animate.css

Me gustaría hacer que cuando le doy en una opción de mi `select` se me despliegue un formulario con una animación y cuando le de click en la otra opción del `select` se haga una animación de salida.

Codigo .js de ocultar

```
$('#pnlDireccion' + conteo).addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
$("#pnlDireccion" + conteo).hide(3000);
```

Codigo .js de mostrar

```
$("#pnlDireccion" + conteo).show();
$('#pnlDireccion' + conteo).addClass('animated bounceInRight');
```

el `hide` lo dejo ya que si lo hago solo con la pura animación sí lo realiza pero ya no puedo volver hacer que se muestre y si lo oculto con `hide` sí, ya que el `show` muestra lo que `hide` oculta, por eso necesito que haga la animación y una vez que termine se ejecute el `hide` y así pueda luego volver a ejecutar `show` para la muestra de nuevo.

Comment: En lugar de `hide`, ¿has probado a quitarle la clase `animated bounceOutLeft` cuando termine la animación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> necesito que haga la animación y una vez que termine se ejecute el hide

Las animaciones de `animate.css` duran un segundo, por ende puedes ocultar el formulario en cuando acabe la animación haciendo un timeout de 1s.

```
$('#pnlDireccion' + conteo).addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
window.setTimeout(function () {
  $('#pnlDireccion' + conteo).hide();
}, 1000);
```

**Usando Velocity**

Si quieres tener un mejor control de las animaciones, entonces te puede servir [`Velocity`](http://velocityjs.org). Es una excelente librería para animaciones que, al contrario de Animate.css, se basa en JavaScript y te permite tener un control del ciclo de vida de las animaciones.

> Velocity se puede usar con o sin jQuery. El modo de usar es indéntica para ambos.

Velocity, usando jQuery acepta dos parámetros:

1. Objeto de propiedades CSS la cuales se van a animar
2. Objeto de opciones

En el objeto de opciones podemos pasarle una función a la propiedad [`complete`](http://velocityjs.org/#beginAndComplete), la cual **se ejecutará una vez completada** la animación. Por ejemplo:

```js
$('#selectForm').on('change', function () {
 let action = $(this).val();
  
  if (action === '') { 
   return;
  }  
  if (action === 'show') {
   $('form').velocity('transition.bounceRightIn');
  } else {
   $('form').velocity('transition.bounceRightOut', {
     complete: function () {
       console.log('Animación completa');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
form {
  margin: 20px  auto;
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.4.2/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.4.2/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>


<select id="selectForm">
  <option value="">Seleccionar opción</option>
  <option value="show">Mostrar formulario</option>
  <option value="hide">Ocultar formulario</option>
</select>

<form>
  <label for="name">Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
</form>
```